# SQL Group by Column1, Column2, Column3, but take row where max(column4) and column4 < 6

Tags: mysql

I have a large sql query that I would like to group by 3 separate columns. But when I do, I would like to compare and select the row based on another column. If I have a query like

```
SELECT
column1,
column2,
column3,
column4,
column5,
FROM table_1 as t1
GROUP BY t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3
```

My issue is that the group by will always take the first result in the table. I need to add in a condition/case that says *IF there is more then one, take the row with largest value in column4 thats < 6.*

```
column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5
 bill   |   kyle  |   smit  |   1     |    a
 bill   |   kyle  |   smit  |   5     |    b
 bill   |   kyle  |   smit  |   6     |    c
```

In the above example the current query will always return the first row. I need it to return the middle row.

I've tried adding `max(column4)` to the select part but that only change that specific column, resulting in the wrong row data returned where column5 = a.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a group by, but no aggregates, so I dont even know how your query is going.  However, that being said, how about

```
order by
   column1,
   column2,
   column3,
   case when column4 > 1 and column4 < 6
        then 1 else 2 end,
   column4 desc
```

This will, within a given Col1, 2, 3, float any records that column4 is greater than 1 and less than 6 to a primary position via then 1 else 2 as its sort, THEN whatever column 4 is descending order after that.

Now, because you could have multiple entries of Col1, 2, 3, AND if you only want the first one PER given Col1, 2, 3, you will need to apply a row-ranking per entry.  This way you can filter only for the first that was found.  Something like

```
select
      PQ.*
   from
      ( SELECT
              column1,
              column2,
              column3,
              column4,
              column5,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER( 
                 PARTITION BY column1, column2, column3
                 ORDER BY case when column4 < 6 then 1 else 2 end,
                          column4 desc ) AS MyRow
           FROM 
              table_1 t1 ) PQ
   where
      PQ.MyRow = 1
```

There is no "Group By", but by using windows function, the partitioning starts the ROW_NUMBER() back to 1 after each given col1, 2, 3.  But the data for each Col1, 2, 3 is returned based on the ORDER BY clause which floats the values less than 6 to the top, then anything else as previously described.  So, if your data had values in column4 such as 2, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10, the rows would be returned in an order of 5, 3, 2, 10, 9, 8.  In this case, the FIRST record in the returned set would be the #5 and the rest just fall in line after that.